# Clear error message from Sublime Text 2 status bar

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

How do I remove the error message in the `status bar` (which appears at the bottom of Sublime Text 2)?

I installed the Git Sublime Text 2 Package using Package Control and then ran git branch on a folder. I received an error message that appeared in the `status bar` and it won't go away!

Comment: I want to know too. Now I open "file" menu - "New view into file", and close the old view.

Answer (score 1):

You can just hit escape to close it.